# A Webservice API client JAR file

Tags: java, rest, maven

I have a set 30 RESTful and 20 Soap services that exposes CRUD functionality to a database.  I have multiple applications that will require access to these APIS.  For the sake of reuse and avoiding code replication I've created a JAR file that consumes theses service, parses the responses and prepares business objects.  This JAR file will be then added as a maven dependency to the clients that require to talk to the RESTFul API.

My question is how can I abstract out the endpoint configurations to a properties file so that consumers of the JAR can configure the end point depending on their environment?

Comment: How are you configuring end point in your jar code?

Comment: There will be a Config bean that reads the properties file and populate the config bean.  I was thinking either java.util.properties or apache commons configurations to implement the properties file.  I could also use spring properties if it makes things managable